# cmd batch redirecting (appending) to file given by variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd

For some unknown reason the following code in my batch script

```
:subroutine    
IF /I %firstPass%==true head -n 1 "%1%" >> "%exFilename%"
```

renders as

```
IF /I true == true head -n 1 ""request_sql.csv"exFilename"
```

The problem is that redirection >> is drops out and the command stumbles. Using plain string for identification of the file works ok. Would be thankful for help.

Comment: Please post some more code! This is not enough to understand what's happening.

Comment: thy like this : `IF /I %firstPass%==true head -n 1 "%~1%" >> "%exFilename%"`

Comment: Did you assign a variable called `1` (like `set 1=...`), or do you want to access the first parameter passed to the batch file (`%1`, see `call /?`)? as you can see, to expand (read) a variable `1` like `%1%` conflicts with the parameter expansion syntax `%1`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
                                   first argument = "request_sql.csv"
                                   vv
IF /I %firstPass%==true head -n 1 "%1%" >> "%exFilename%"
                                     ^......^
                                      undefined variable
```

And you get

```
IF /I true == true head -n 1 ""request_sql.csv"exFilename"
```

As the correct way to reference the first argument is `%1`, without closing percent sign, you should use

```
IF /I "%firstPass%"=="true" head -n 1 "%~1" >> "%exFilename%"
```

where `%~1` is the content of the first argument without quotes, as you are including them in the command